# Place position absolute elements at equal distance with-in a container

Tags: javascript

I am creating a sortable drag and drop piece where users can sort and reorder the grid items as they like. I am placing the items with position absolute to get the animation correct.

Basically, I have a container and there will be n number of elements in a row and I need to place these items at equal distances from each other.
[image]

I need to find a reliable way to calculate the left values of each element so that it can be placed correctly.

The following is my current code:

```
let rowElemsCount= 4;

const arrangeItems = (items,rowElemsCount,container,elemWidth,elemHight) => {
    elemHight= elemHight|| elemWidth;
    let containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
    let containerHeight = Math.ceil(items.length / rowElemsCount) * elemHight;
    container.style.height =  containerHeight + "px";
    items.forEach((item,i)=>{
        let pos = {
            x: (i%rowElemsCount) * elemWidth+ "px",
            y: Math.floor(i/rowElemsCount) * elemHight+ "px"
        };

        item.style.cssText = "top:"+pos.y+";left:"+pos.x+";"
        item.dataset.index = i;
    });
}
```

I use this method to organize the elements, the calculation for the top is perfect but for the left, it just places the elements one after the other. I need to someway replicate the justify-content: space-between for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to calculate the white space between your elements in your calculations. If you add up the width of all the children's containers, then subtract it from the width of the parent you get the leftover whitespace you need to break into fractions.

```
parent width - children total width = leftover whitespace
```

if the white space is to only be divided into portions between the children elements, you should then divide that leftover whitespace by children count -1 because the first element doesn't need padding

```
leftover whitespace / ( children - 1 ) = space between
```

now your left is just that leftover white plus the left value

```
item index * ( element width + white space )
```

Now they should be spaced correctly. You're very close with your current code, and implementing these changes should be pretty easy!